# Is a 'special' web hosting required for MEAN webapps?

Tags: web-hosting

I designed some websites with HTML, jQuery and PHP. Now I want to start learning deveolpment with MEAN full stack. And the question is:

Is 'special' web hosting required to host MEAN webapps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MEAN means MongoDB + express + Angular + node. 
Out of it, Only MongoDB is server dependent.

Rest of them are JS, for JS to work there is no special requirement from server.

To have a MEAN stack, you need mongoDB support from your hosting company.

Answer (score 0):

To run MEAN stack, you need node js server and database backend will be mongodb.

Express is a framework which run on node server.
Angular js is javascript framework that run on both ( server side and client side)

To start with MEAN, have a try at REDHAT Openshift Free tiers computing cloud or try google cloud (trial )